# Typing delay using angular-ui codemirror

Tags: angularjs, codemirror, ui-codemirror

I have used angular ui codemirror in textarea for syntax highlighting, line numbers, formatting functionality.

But after integrating ui-codemirror, I am facing typing delay in text area. same delay will occurs if user tries to delete the contents from textarea.

I am using angular.js 1.0.8, codemirror version 4, angular ui codemirror directive.

Does anyone have solution for this?

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: Do you try to  have typing delay ? I did not get it totally?

Comment: @katmanco: When I type anything in textarea continuously and then stops at that time, some characters will be displayed after fraction of second, cursor also get stuck for some milliseconds. Same when I tries to delete continuously characters will be deleted after some fraction of seconds not  instantly.